# want 2 slider row at a time

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have around 40 to 50 logos in my website and they all are in slider it takes to much time to see whole slider.

**Here It is**
[image]

Here my code...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="logo slider" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
<?php foreach ($logo $row): ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center sm-margin-nine-bottom xs-margin-fifteen-bottom">
        <div class="">
            <a href="#">
                <img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>uploads/<?php echo $row->image; ?>" style="height: 250px;width: 2000px;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>       
<?php endforeach; ?>
</section>
```

Now I want to show 2 rows of my logo section like **This**
[image]

Any suggestion how can i do it...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which jQuery slider you are using?

Comment: I use Slick Slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using modulo in `foreach` loop and join odd / even like this -

```
<section class="logo slider" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($logo as $row): ?>
<?php if($i%2 == 0){ ?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center sm-margin-nine-bottom xs-margin-fifteen-bottom">
    <div class="">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>uploads/<?php echo $row->image; ?>" style="height: 250px;width: 2000px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>uploads/<?php echo $row->image; ?>" style="height: 250px;width: 2000px;">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php  }  $i++;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I don't know much about php so please forgive for any syntax error.

Comment: Avoid `Thanks` in comments.. this (one of best or I want to say "Top of the Best" ) community site is made for helping developers only, so better is to help some another.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you split the array in half using the array_slice function.

eg:

```
$array_length = count($logo);
$slider_one = array_slice($logo, 0, $array_length / 2);
$slider_two = array_slice($logo, $array_length / 2);
```

You would then have two for each loops on the front end to display slider one and two.